# Does OkHttp3 support HTTP2 via a HTTP forward proxy?

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 in my Android app to make HTTP/1.x requests to my backend servers via a forward proxy, like so:

```
List<Protocol> protos = new ArrayList<>();
protos.add(Protocol.HTTP_2);
protos.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress("proxy.example.com", 80);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyAddr);
OkHttpClient cli = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .proxy(proxy)
    .protocols(protos)
    .build();
String url = "http://www.example.com/";
Request req = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
Response res = cli.newCall(req).execute();
```

I would like to upgrade to HTTP2. However, it seems to me that OkHttp3 can make HTTP2 requests only if we are not going via a HTTP proxy. So, the above code wouldn't work.

In other words, OkHttp3 supports the first 3 cases below but not the fourth. HTTP/2 below means h2 (HTTP/2 over TLS) not h2c (HTTP/2 over clear text).

a) client <-- HTTP/1.x --> upstream server

b) client <-- HTTP/1.x --> forward proxy <-- HTTP/x --> upstream server

c) client <-- HTTP/2   --> upstream server

d) client <-- HTTP/2   --> forward proxy <-- HTTP/x --> upstream server

Does anyone confirm or deny my understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp will do HTTP/2 over an HTTP proxy. You’ll need HTTPS on the server since OkHttp doesn’t implement plaintext HTTP/2.

Comment: Jesse, I am a SO newbie and I have a follow-up question which can't be expressed cleanly in a comment - I don't know how to. Please see the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse, I tried retrieving https://www.google.com/ with Proxy.Type.HTTP via nghttp2's forward proxy nghttpx, which supports HTTP2 over TLS. Unfortunately, TLS handshaking did not happen and the forward proxy reported the following error.

... tls: handshake libssl error: error:1407609B:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:https proxy request

From what I gather, this error means that okhttp3's proxy code is not doing TLS handshaking with the forward proxy.

This makes me think that HTTP2 over TLS via a forward proxy is kind of pointless, because the forward proxy won't be able to add any value to encrypted requests - the forward proxy is just a pass-through pipe. In fact, I think TLS via any forward proxy is pointless. End-to-end HTTP2 over TLS does make sense, but via a forward proxy doesn't.